# How to get Django Cache Machine to work on django.contrib.auth.models.User?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-contrib, django-cache-machine

I'm using [**Django Cache Machine**](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-cache-machine) to cache my Django ORM objects. It's a great piece of software. It has immensely reduced the database accesses for nearly all my models -- and it is simple to use.

However, one model is still not being cached: `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. Because that is not my own application code, I didn't outfit it with the `CachingMixin` that Cache Machine instructions tell you to add to each of your models. So now even though all my own applications' models are being cached, the `User` model is not. And so there are still numerous unneccesary database accesses.

What is the best way to eliminate these database accesses? `django.contrib.auth.models.User` is not part of my code-base in Git. I would prefer not altering the source code of that class or module at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) which preserves the functionality of the Dajgno User model while adding the caching mixin.

I'm guessing this would be enough:

```
from caching.base import CachingManager, CachingMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager

class CachedUserManager(CachingManager, UserManager):
    pass

class CachedUser(CachingMixin, AbstractUser):
    objects = CachedUserManager()
```

and of course, in your settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.CachedUser'
```

Comment: Thank you Anentropic. This looks like a great solution.